# ATtiny85 and nRF24L01+ only work with longer Vcc/GND lines on PCB

Tags: nrf24l01, attiny85

I'm trying to build something small and battery powered. I have a handful of ATtiny85s and nRF24L01+s.

I have breadboarded it using the 3-pin method described on [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/NRF24L01-With-ATtiny85-3-Pins/) and it works (I have a Pi set up to simply listen and print out the message and that is how I monitor the success of the radio). My next goal is/was to start building a PCB, then a case, etc.

The boards turn out pretty decently (I'm just using single-sided for now) and I've added a 2x4 header for it to plug into on the PCB, but I cannot get the board to work for the life of me plugged into that header.

I have etched about 10 different boards in different configurations, some with <strike>ground planes</strike> copper fill, some without, decoupling capacitors, etc.

This is my latest iteration:

[image]

Please note the decoupling caps on the ATtiny85 as well as the two (electrolytic and ceramic) on the nRF24L01+.

I found if I add at least 16 mm of wire on both the VCC and GND pins to the nRF24L01+ it works, but if I use the shorter (11 mm) jumpers on those two lines, it doesn't work. I've tried multiple cables/wires/etc., however, I get the same voltage when checking the header pins on the nRF24L01+ as I do on the board (3.017 VDC). All the other communication lines work fine.

I have a 10-pack from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00O9O868G) and plugged various ones into other boards and they all work as expected; I just cannot for the *life* of me get it to work in a small form package without pulling it away from the board.

I found if I physically place the module where the headers are (with the longer wires attached) it still works. I've even face-planted the antenna and face of the nRF24L01+ into the tiny IC, batteries, and it still fires away.

A few suggestions on other forums/boards have recommended putting the nRF24L01+ away from the board or turning it perpendicular (I tried this and it made no difference). I have seen other people successfully stack these boards on [mySensors](https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/5995/pcb-design-with-nrf24l01-and-arduino-pro-mini), [here](http://www.cinestesia.io/mini-nrf24l01/), with an Arduinos, Pis, and Nanos (oh my). So it *has* to be possible to be on a minimal PCB.

There must be something I'm missing (hopefully something stupid and small); any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

PCB iterations:

- <strike>Ground plane</strike> Copper fill
- no <strike>ground plane</strike> copper fill
- all lines traced to other side (not under board)
- jumpers
- perf board

**TL;DR:**

The nRF24L01+ transmits only when I use a longer lead for GND and VCC off the PCB.

[image: copper traces]

I used a <strike>ground plane</strike> copper fill on this one...

[image: pcb with wires]

[image]

Code:

```
#define CE_PIN 3
#define CSN_PIN 3 // Since we are using 3 pin configuration we will use same pin for both CE and CSN

#include "RF24.h" // https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_1MBPS);
  radio.setChannel(0x76);
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1);

  delay(1000);

  const char text[] = "Starting up!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
}

void loop(void) {
  const char text[] = "Hello World Hello World. 123456";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));    

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Is ATTiny85 pin 1 unconnected? Normally the RESET# pin should have a 10k pullup resistor to VCC, otherwise the device might be stuck in reset.

Comment: Nitpick: If it's single layer, it's not a ground plane as used for signal integrity, but a ground FILL. I.e. less impedance on your ground lines at DC.

Comment: So, supply voltage is about 3.0V ? What is the speed (frequency) of the AVR? What is the consumption of thre AVR and NRF module? What kind of battery it is and can it provide the necessary current without dropping voltage too much?

Comment: @MarkU - I don't have it connected on this board. It didn't seem to make a difference right now (my serial monitor doesn't indicate a reset-loop).

Comment: @Araho - Noted, thanks - still working on the vernacular

Comment: @Justme - Yes, ~3.0V - x2 fresh Alkaline AA's.
I've tried the AVR at 16, 8, and it's currently at 1mhz. 
The avr is using 3.76mA as of now and the nrf uses about 0.65mA when it's transmitting (though my multimeter might not be fast enough to catch a higher hit) (4.3mA total when running and transmitting)

Comment: Are you sure you have the polarity of the clock set correctly for the SPI communications? If you had it incorrect it could be extremely sensitive any wiring changes. Can you provide a link to your software?

Comment: @KevinWhite - I've uploaded the basic sketch and a link to the RF library I'm using (it's a comment in the code). The pins declared don't seem to make a difference - it still runs fine with the longer GND and VCC leads.

Comment: Your sketch isn't quite right. SCK and CSN are shared, not CE and CSN. CE is tied high. You should set CE_PIN to something that doesn't exist like 7.

Comment: The author of the 3-pin method has slightly modified the RF24 library (see http://nerdralph.blogspot.com/2014/01/nrf24l01-control-with-3-attiny85-pins.html). Have you made the same change? The timing seems to be quite delicate.

Comment: @Codo - I had used the modified version of the library, however it seemed like there were extra steps needed. I needed to use another library to determine a settle high and low value for my nRF, then modify the core library with those values... It looks like that solved it! Post this as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

What your're doing when adding the extra VCC/GND wire for the nRF24 is to insert some inductance and resistance. I assume that this decouples the nRF24 power supply from the ATTiny power supply.

Radios like the nRF24 tend to draw **a lot** of current in a very short time, i.e. when the radio is activated.

From your schematic and layout, I can only see **very little** capacitance (also the 10 μF is not that much and because it's an ALU type cap, it has high ESR.

I think you need to provide much more (low ESR) capacitance to your circuit, because the high current peaks of the nRF24 might disrupt your power supply.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I thought I was decoupling the nRF24 with my caps already, but I swapped the ceramic .1uF out for .47uF and a larger electrolytic of 47uF from 10uF. I also added a 300ms delay before starting up the nRF24 radio in code, but still no go.